# how can i fix error: "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"?

Tags: python, datetime, jupyter-notebook, data-science, tweets

I have a dataset containing various columns of created_at, text, author.id, i am trying to do a time analysis:

```
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['author.created_at'])
    df = df.set_index('date') 
    timestamp = (df_time!=0).resample('AS').sum()
```

I am getting error as:

[image]TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex,
TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Can anyone help me with this?Thank you

Comment: it seems you set the index to `df` but resample another DataFrame, `df_time`?

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realise that. Now, it worked :)